# How to set different directory for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

By default jenkins build code in "var/lib/jenkins/workspace/" directory. I installed the git plugin but there is the option for sub-directory. Is there any way we can build it in differt directory like "/root" for diffrent repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Advanced button on the right side of the Job's config page

Check "Use custom workspace"

Fill in the path to the desired folder path.